# Can't deploy my laravel app to render via GitHub

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, web-deployment, vendor

I was trying to deploy my laravel app to render.com
I followed this tutorial : https://render.com/docs/deploy-php-laravel-docker
I've **laravel 8** , **php 8.0.0** , **composer 2**
these are my logs of deployment :

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18
```

this my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running composer"
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
composer install --no-dev --working-dir=/var/www/html

echo "Caching config..."
php artisan config:cache

echo "Caching routes..."
php artisan route:cache

echo "Running migrations..."
php artisan migrate --force
```

Comment: Does `artisan` exist in your Github library? Do you have a `.gitignore` which is ignoring it? Have you checked the contents of `/var/www/html` to see if everything is as expected? What debug have you actually done?

Comment: yes I've artisan and i have also the .gitignore file , but how can I check the /var/www/html ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have issues when installing composer dependencies. I had PHP version issues when installing some packages. Edit the `Dockerfile` and make sure to use the latest version of `nginx-php-fpm`.

The tutorial you have given uses `1.9.1`. I upgraded to `2.2.0`.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:2.2.0

COPY . .

# Image config
ENV SKIP_COMPOSER 1
ENV WEBROOT /var/www/html/public
ENV PHP_ERRORS_STDERR 1
ENV RUN_SCRIPTS 1
ENV REAL_IP_HEADER 1

# Laravel config
ENV APP_ENV production
ENV APP_DEBUG false
ENV LOG_CHANNEL stderr

# Allow composer to run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```